# Boostrap inline-forms layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working with bootstrap and I'm trying to make a simple page that contains a list of input boxes and dropdowns with the `form-inline` approach.

I would like the form fields obviously to be at equal distances between them, and, if possibile, to make the size relative to the label and field length. This is the ugly result I get, just to explain:

[image]

As you can see from the code below, I gave a col size of 3 for each field trying to make each row contain 4 inputs, but the result is ugly: if the label is too long I can't see the content of the dropdown, the spacing between each input depends on the length of the input, so the result is not eye-catching.

The next problem is the vertical spacing between inputs. Obviously everything should be in the same form to make a single submit, and this is the result when an input requires a new line. I obviously would like to have a nice vertical spacing but I don't know how to.

This is the code of the page:

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="it-it" lang="it-it">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="" />
  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../resources/miotema/favicon.ico" />
  <title>Tool fgfgfg</title>
  <script src="<c:url value="/resources/miotema/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" />" type="text/javascript" ></script>
  <script src="<c:url value="/resources/miotema/js/bootstrap.min.js" />" type="text/javascript" ></script>
  <script src="<c:url value="/resources/miotema/js/common.js" />" type="text/javascript" ></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/resources/miotema/css/bootstrap.min.css" />" type="text/css" />

 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="navbar navbar-default">
   <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">

     <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right menu header">
      <li class="dropdown">
       <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">TEST<span class="caret"></span></a>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="<c:url value="/studi/visualizza" />">Visualizza </a></li>
        <li><a href="<c:url value="/studi/crea" />">Nuovo</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Voce Menu separato</a></li>
       </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="javascript:chiamataAjax()">Chiamata Ajax</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:doLogoutAction()">Logout</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid">

<form class="form-inline" action="<c:url value="/insert" />"
    method="post">
    <div class="well bs-component">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Inserimento Dati</legend>


            <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><strong>testtttttttttttt</strong></span> <select class="form-control"
                        name="durata_contrattuale">
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><strong>uahuaduhaudhtfftftftftftftfuadu</strong></span> <select class="form-control" name="capacita_banda">
                        <option>10 Mb/s</option>
                        <option>20 Mb/s</option>
                        <option>30 Mb/s</option>
                        <option>40 Mb/s</option>
                        <option>50 Mb/s</option>
                        <option>60 Mb/s</option>
                        <option>70 Mb/s</option>
                        <option>80 Mb/s</option>
                        <option>90 Mb/s</option>
                        <option>100 Mb/s</option>
                        <option>200 Mb/s</option>
                        <option>300 Mb/s</option>
                        <option>Altro</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><strong>fy</strong></span> <select class="form-control"
                        name="opzione_realizzazione">
                        <option>Basic</option>
                        <option>Plus</option>
                        <option>Ultra</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><strong>dtddtdttd</strong></span> <select class="form-control" name="ultra_protezione">
                        <option>Si</option>
                        <option>No</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>



    <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><strong>blablabalbala</strong></span>
            <select class="form-control" name="lbublbu">
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>5</option>

            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    </fieldset>
    </div>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Any hint?

Comment: Not sure if this will fix your issue, but you may want a `<div class="row">` between  your container and col-lg-3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all you missed "**ROW**" class element that will serve as **parent** for all **col-3**'s you made. Second there is **5 col-3**'s**** which means grid of **15** not **12** as it should be. Try to count which of the inputs should be bigger than others, and count down how many col's you need. After that make it **sum** **equal** to **12** and also you might try to put `width: 100%;` for input.

Comment: So I declare `<div class="row">` containing each of them 4 form-groups with `col-md-3` class?

Comment: Yes, but you might want for example ROW and than col-1 , col-3, col-2, col-6. Try to see if that helps you to layout things down. You can go if you got 5 elements with ROW and than col-1 , col-3, col-2, col-4, col-2.

Comment: Ok, like this I can give the size I want to each of the fields, but I guess there's no way to make uniform horizontal spacing between each of the fields, right?

Comment: well bootstrap will do it for you, but you need to assign width: 100% to the input element, so it can occupy the whole div. Try it like that. You'll get horizontal space, which also you can control later on by givving padding to the parent div that holds inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@media (min-width: 992px){
    .bs-component .form-control{
        margin-bottom: 15px; 
    }
}
```